# running composer from upstart

Tags: node.js, upstart, composer

I am running Ubuntu 14.04.

I am trying to make a service capable of deploying an application. The process is very simple:

1. I have a node script listening on port `2133` for a `POST` request
2. When this script gets a request, it triggers a bash script that has to clone a git repository
3. The bash script should run a `composer install` command to install the dependencies of the application.

When I launch my script with `node index.js`, everything works fine.

I then made an upstart service, defined with the following config file:

```
description "Service permettant le déploiement d'une application depuis bitbucket"
author "Mathieu Marteau"

start on filesystem runlevel [2345]
stop on shutdown
respawn
setuid mmarteau

exec /usr/bin/node /home/mmarteau/deploy/index.js
```

The service works fine, all of my bash file is running, except for the one command `composer install`.

I've got nothing in the `/var/log/upstart/myservice.log`.

I also tried to replace the `composer install` command with the full path: `/usr/local/bin/composer install;` but this has no effect either.

Where should I look to solve my problem?

Thank you very much for your help!

**EDIT: My problem is solved when I replace the `composer install` by `sudo composer install`. 
I don't understand because everything works when I launch my node script logged as `mmarteau` but it does need a `sudo` with the upstart service. I thought that the `setuid mmarteau` was the necessary line...**

Comment: Check current working directory. I'm pretty sure it's `/` and probably composer doesn't expect that

Comment: I placed a `pwd;` in my bash script to check that, and it shows the right directory... Before running composer, I `cd` into the directory in by bash script

Comment: The problem is solved when I replace the `composer install;` by `sudo composer install`. But I'm not sure that this is the proper solution...